# Call a code behind function from javascript in aspx

Tags: c#, javascript, code-behind

I have a page where a javascript will be triggered when the user closes the browser tabs / browser window. Language is in c# thanks.

im using window.onbeforeunload, something along the line like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    window.onbeforeunload = myFunction;


function myFunction()
{
    //call my function here
}
```

the code behind function will be a simple function for now, so no input parameters or return value are needed. So i'll just like to know how to call my function (eg: public void callMyFunction())

Comment: I think you're confused here... javascript code runs in the browser (client) and C# code runs in the server. You can't call C# code from javascript. At most, you could call a webservice exposed on the server via an AJAX call.

Comment: Or use Page Methods. Good tutorial: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx

Comment: @axel_c~ What makes you think that you can't call c# code from javascript? I've done it many times.. Just call button.click() from your javascript and be suprised!

Comment: @Pabuc that's triggering a client-side event that happens to post back to the server and execute C# code, not directly calling C# code from javascript. It's a different thing.

Comment: well.. Then you should have said "You can't write C# code into javascript function".

Answer (score 3):

There are variety mechanisms to call your code-behind function(s). You could use an [Ajax Call](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/), Page Methods, [ASP.NET Client Callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163941.aspx), or even trigger a code-behind handler using an [invisible ASP.NET button](http://forums.asp.net/p/1636721/4227032.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try the sample code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        windown.OnUnload(){ function(){ $("#Btn_Click").click();}};
    </script>

</head>
<body>
...

 <asp:Button ID="Btn_Click" runat="server" Text="ButtonClick" onClick="Btn_Click" />
...
</body>
</html>
```

hope it helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

By using Ajax you can access code behind method from javascript .
   Try this code.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     classname.methodname();
    </script>
```

In code behind page:
in page load you need to register follwing code...

```
pageload()
{
      AjaxPro.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(pagename), this.Page);
}



[AjaxPro.AjaxMethod(AjaxPro.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]
    public void methodname()
    {
    ..........
    ........
    }
```

Here classname is code behind page class name